# How come i'm getting this error outofboundsException?

Tags: java

I don't seem to be getting any other errors except this one:        Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 
I looked it up and it says i'm trying to get a value that isn't in my array list. I'm not sure where I went wrong with this.

```
import java.util.*;
 class DebugNine1
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  String[][] books = new String[6][2]; 
  books[0][0] = "Ulysses";
  books[0][1] = "James Joyce";
  books[1][0] = "Lolita";
  books[1][1] = "Vladimir Nabokov";
  books[2][1] = "Huckleberry Finn";
  books[2][1] = "Mark Twain";
  books[3][0] = "Great Gatsby";
  books[3][2] = "F. Scott Fitzgerald";
  books[4][0] = "1984";
  books[4][1] = "George Orwell";
  books[5][5] = "Sound and the Fury";
  books[5][1] = "William Faulkner";

  String entry,
     shortEntry,
     message ="Enter the first three characters of a book title omitting \"A\" or \"The\" ";
  int num, x;
  boolean isFound = true;
  while(isFound)
  {
     System.out.println(message);
     entry = input.next();
     shortEntry = entry.substring(0,3);
     for(x = 0; x < books.length; ++x)
        if(books[x][0].startsWith(entry))
        {
           isFound = false;
           System.out.println(books[x][0] + " was written by " + books[x][1]);
           x = books.length;
        }
     if(isFound)
        System.out.println("Sorry - no such book in our database");
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Mark the line where the exception occurs.

Comment: Check out F. Scott Fitzgerald

Comment: I never thought that a programming question would get a literary answer

Comment: And after "F. Scott Fitzgerald", read also "Sound and the Fury".

Comment: Seriously though, time to learn to use your debugger. You'll need the skills moving forward.

Comment: You seem to have a typo on the lines with Huckleberry Finn, F. Scott Fitzgerald, and Sound and the Fury

Comment: You may find it easier to use an array initializer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the following two lines:

```
books[3][2] = "F. Scott Fitzgerald";
...
books[5][5] = "Sound and the Fury";
```

Change them to

```
books[3][1] = "F. Scott Fitzgerald";
...
books[5][0] = "Sound and the Fury";
```

Note that your array has been declared as follows:

```
String[][] books = new String[6][2];
```

which means you can have only `0` or `1` as the index value for the second dimension.

In addition to the problems mentioned above, you should also consider changing the first of the following two lines otherwise you will have `null` at `books[2][0]`:

```
books[2][1] = "Huckleberry Finn";
books[2][1] = "Mark Twain";
```

Change it to

```
books[2][0] = "Huckleberry Finn";
```